# Signature of method that returns a LinkedHashMap<K,V>

Tags: java, collections, interface

Consider that I want method `foo` to return a `LinkedHashMap`(data is ordered by insertion order). The reason being that this `Map` will be populated by a database and I want it to reflect the order that is returned from the query. What would be the correct way of defining the signature of the method?

1. `public LinkedHashMap<String, String> foo()`
2. `public Map<String, String> foo()`

The first would have the advantage of advertising to clients that the map is ordered, while the second would be more general.

Comment: ideally there'd be an OrderedMap interface, ala SortedMap, and then i'd say you could return that.  The question is, does the client of this method need to know this? or does it just iterate and voila the items are just ordered.

Comment: In this case, it might be better to document what the order is. A LinkedHashMap might have access order, or be ordered in ways the caller might not expect so better to document it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely the second one - you should prefer interfaces and hide implementation - if you will decide in the future to use another implementation of `Map` you won't need to change anything in another method using this code

Also notice that you are not allowed to overload methods by return type so using general type seems to be appropriate

Comment: But in this case wouldn't it be good for the clients to know the implementation, i.e. that the Map is ordered?

Comment: If client must know type of map and you would end with using `instanceof` then you should not have a problem here ;)

Comment: The reason being that this Map will be populated by a database and I want it to reflect the order that is returned from the query.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how this method is going to be used/specialized. However, I would recommend the second appoach.

Consider a scenario where this method needs to be overridden to return let's say sorted values (i.e. `TreeMap`) or unsorted/unordered values (`HashMap`). In this case, we won't be able to `override` this method and will have to create another method(s).

Comment: You can do `Map<K,V> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();` and it would still maintain the insertion order